# ruby "permission denied" installing/using homebrew cask

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

My wild bet is that this issue is somehow related to my base osx `ruby` setup... but as I'm not a ruby-ite, i need some guidance to discover more.

A couple days ago i tried to install a `brew cask` formula (several others were already installed previously).  A couple weeks ago i upgraded to OSX Sierra.

Brew itself works perfectly, brew `cask` does not.

I get an "unexpected" error when I type `brew cask` by itself or with any subcommand:

```
Error: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for st.h... yes
checking for rb_str_replace() in ruby.h... yes
creating Makefile
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:2125:in `initialize': Permission denied - Makefile (Errno::EACCES)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:2125:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:2125:in `create_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/msgpack-0.5.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.0.0/msgpack-0.5.8/gem_make.out
```

I've looked through many questions and tried many of the answers given, all to no avail.

> Questions:
>   [Homebrew cask option not recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30413621/1600630)
>   [Failed to build gem native extension (installing Compass)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22544754/1600630)
>   [homebrew not working on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24652996/1600630)     [Can't install Brew
>   formulae correctly (Permission denied in /usr/local/lib)](https://superuser.com/questions/254843/cant-install-brew-formulae-correctly-permission-denied-in-usr-local-lib)
>   [OsX, can't use Homebrew because of Ruby permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40927546/1600630)

Attempts:

```
> xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

> brew install ruby
Warning: ruby-2.4.0 already installed

> ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/
drwxr-xr-x 7 root wheel 238 2017-01-12 12:12:13 2.0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   3 2017-01-09 09:47:51 Current -> 2.0

> sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
> sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local

> brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
> brew cask [list|cleanup|update|etc]
(gives error shown above)
```

Performed a complete homebrew uninstall, `rm`'ing extra dirs and files. Then complete homebrew re-install, followed by re-install many of the formulae I had previously.

Same commands above give same errors after reinstall.

Color me confused. 😕

Comment: Since this relates to Homebrew and might be a bug in the software you might want to file an issue on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew). This only peripherally relates to programming.

Comment: True on the brew-cask-bug possibility.  I posted it here as I think it is related to my system, but it's the use of the brew-cask that shows the problem.

Comment: I've had minor problems with Homebrew before and they're pretty good about addressing them quickly. The `cask` project may be a bit different but it's worth filing a ticket if you can reproduce this. For example, spin up a VM with a pristine install and try the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

So I just resolved something similar - it was a permissions issue for me. I ended up running:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) your-directory-here
```

on the Cask and caskroom directories - you may have to look around a little bit to find those directories on your system.